# How to get the local timezone of the system from Django?

Tags: python, django, django-timezone

I am entering the time from a local machine at a timezone +5:30. My `TIME_ZONE` is set to `UTC` in the `settings.py` file. Now the user entering the data from the `django admin` is entering it in his own local time zone which could be anywhere in the world. What I am thinking about is `how do I convert this time into UTC before storing it in the DB?` I need to store all data in the DB in `UTC` only. Any ideas?

Comment: You can't, unless you know the timezone of the "user entering the data".

Comment: @Aya Isnt there any widget or something? Some javascript to return the local timezone?

Comment: Sure, but you'd probably also want to change the displayed data to the local user's timezone also. According to [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9690114/how-do-you-make-django-admin-timezone-aware) there's currently no built-in way to do that.

Comment: @Aya Thats bad. :( Any idea on how to over ride the django admin to do that?

Comment: Nope. Might be easiest to put a big warning at the top of the admin template which reads. "Please enter all dates/times in UTC".

Comment: Yeah I have already put up a helptext beside the date time field. But thats not very easy on the user is it?

Comment: To clarify, I meant that I'm not aware of a way to override the behavior, although that doesn't necessarily mean there isn't a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should get timezone of the user or time difference.

*Example by time difference*

Firstly, on client side you must get time difference:

> ```
> //JavaScript
> d = new Date()
> d.getTimezoneOffset()
> // print
> -240
> ```

Secondly, time with the different should be converted to timestamp and send to server side. On the serverside from timestamp you can get time that can be saved to database.

Comment: I am entering the data from the django admin. Do I have any control over the data before sending it to the django server?

Comment: Yes, at the templates. Usually, django's admin will show time depending on settings. If set USE_TZ = True at the settings time at the Django's admin should be UTC. But I understood you haven't it. Am I right?

Comment: No. I have set `USE_TZ = True` in my settings file. So the problem exists. Also if the users clicks time now then it should show the utc time right? And if thats the case, what happens if the user enter the time manually?

Answer (score -2):

go to settings.py of your Django project

comment timezone settings and use  TIME_ZONE = timezone.now()

```
from django.utils import timezone


TIME_ZONE = timezone.now()

# TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
# USE_I18N = True
# USE_L10N = True
# USE_TZ = True
```

Comment: TIME_ZONE must be a string